# How to create features out of lagged values using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I have a csv like this. First line is the header.

```
f1, f2, f3, t
a1, b1, c1, t1
a2, b2, c2, t2
a3, b3, c3, t3
a4, b4, c4, t4
a5, b5, c5, t5
a6, b6, c6, t6
a7, b7, c7, t7
a8, b8, c8, t8
```

I want the following.

```
f1_lag_2, f2_lag_2, f3_lag_2, f1_lag_1, f2_lag_1, f3_lag_1, f1, f2, f3, t
a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2, a3, b3, c3, t3
a2, b2, c2, a3, b3, c3, a4, b4, c4, t4
a3, b3, c3, a4, b4, c4, a5, b5, c5, t5
a4, b4, c4, a5, b5, c5, a6, b6, c6, t6
a5, b5, c5, a6, b6, c6, a7, b7, c7, t7
a6, b6, c6, a7, b7, c7, a8, b8, c8, t8
```

This is what I have come up with, is this correct? Is there a better way to do this?

```py
def lag_variables_to_features(df, num_lags=1):
    df_lagged = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(1, num_lags + 1):  # iterate from num_lags to 1
        for ci, column in enumerate(df.columns[:-1]):  # excluding the last column
            df_lagged.insert(ci, column + '_lag_' + str(i), df[column].shift(i))

    df_lagged = pd.concat([df_lagged, df], axis=1)
    df_lagged = df_lagged.dropna()  # remove rows with NaN values

    return df_lagged
```

Comment: you can use `zip(row_indices. row_indices[1:]. row_indices[2:])`, use the tuples to construct the new rows

Answer (score 1):

Using [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)'s [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html):

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv
from itertools import product

N = 3

ignore_cols = ['t']

tmp = df.drop(columns=ignore_cols)

out = (pd.DataFrame(swv(tmp, (N, 1)).swapaxes(1, 2)
                                    .reshape((df.shape[0]-N+1, -1)),
                    columns=[b+a for a,b in
                             product([f'_lag_{n-1}'
                                      for n in range(N, 1, -1)]+[''],
                                     tmp)]
                   )
         .join(df[ignore_cols].shift(1-N).reset_index(drop=True))
      )
```

Output:

```
  f1_lag_2 f2_lag_2 f3_lag_2 f1_lag_1 f2_lag_1 f3_lag_1  f1  f2  f3   t
0       a1       b1       c1       a2       b2       c2  a3  b3  c3  t3
1       a2       b2       c2       a3       b3       c3  a4  b4  c4  t4
2       a3       b3       c3       a4       b4       c4  a5  b5  c5  t5
3       a4       b4       c4       a5       b5       c5  a6  b6  c6  t6
4       a5       b5       c5       a6       b6       c6  a7  b7  c7  t7
5       a6       b6       c6       a7       b7       c7  a8  b8  c8  t8
```